# Is it possible to disable config file transforms when installing a NuGet package?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a large solution with about 15 projects in it - and most of them recently added the `Essential.Diagnostics.*` NuGet packages.

However these packages include Web.config/App.config transforms that, frankly, horribly mutilate my files with hundreds of lines of useless XML comments and "example" configuration that are added/re-added every single time the package is installed... as we do package upgrades regularly and on all of our different dev machines this becomes very... very annoying, especially if we make a change we *want* to make, then forget to make a git commit, then update packages - our desired changes are lost in the sea.

The current transforms are also very buggy - it will copy-over XML comments, for example, but the way it works means that every time a package upgrade is performed it will duplicate comments - consequently I have a 100+ line section that is just the same 2-line XML comment repeated 50 times-over.

When I do a NuGet package installation or upgrade, is there any option or switch that instructs it to exclude files from being modified? Preferably in the GUI too.

Comment: Not possible as far as I am aware. If the file exists in the project then NuGet will attempt to transform it.

Comment: The only thing you can do is just move your files into a different folder rather than the same folder of the package consists. For ex, if the package consists *.config file in package\content\ *.config, then you have to move the *.config file of your project into a different folder like project\New Folder\ *.config. Then the package will skip the file transformation if the file is not available in the desired folder.

Comment: @MathivananKP That is not an option for `web.config` files which generally must be in the root directory of a web-application.

Comment: in such case, its not possible. :/